# Performance and effective function

Tags: c#, loops

I have a function in C# which has parameter of List of object type. Now the function has for loops which iterates for number of element in a list. And inside a loop there is update sql query and update the field of table with the list[i] elements.

The problem is loop might goes for 2000 times. So, how can i write a function to improve the c# code.

Here is my sample code. So what do need to do?

```
public int UpdateTableAccount(List<Account> ac)
{
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ac.Count; i++)
    {
        if (ac[i].isActive)
        {
            var str = $"UPDATE account SET amount = '{ac[i].amount}' WHERE (AccountId = '{ac[i].AccountId}'";
            j += Convert.ToInt16(dba.ExecuteSQL(str));
        }
    }
    return j;
}
```

Comment: You must look at bulk insert.

Comment: If you are getting a table fro the database use an Adapter to put results in to a c# datatable.  Then after updating values in datatable you can use the Accept Change method which will put modfications back into the database.

Comment: This is quite impossible to answer because you haven't told us what the bottleneck is. If the bottleneck is "executing up to 2000 sql's" then the answer is simple, don't.  Fix your SQL execution method so that it doesn't end up executing 1 sql per item. However, it most likely isn't as easy as simply rewriting the SQL to be "WHERE IN (...)" either as 2000 items in that list is going to trip something else. But before we can help you, what *actually* is the bottleneck here?

Comment: We can use Table Value Parameter as Param to SP and update the table in Stored Procedure.

Comment: I just want to know if there is any way that I can make this code effective as the loop might goes upto 2000 and I guess this reason my application will have performance issue doing back and forth with database.

Comment: What is your database? Is the stored procedure allowed to your application?

Comment: My database is Microsoft Sql server and yes stored procedure is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, calling Database update inside loop is not advisable. This should be avoided. It not only creates performance issue but other issues too.

If the database is `MS-SQL server` and the application allows `Stored Procedure` then, we can use Table-Valued Parameters to solve this issue.

1. Create [User Defined Table Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/bb522526(v=sql.100))

   ```
   CREATE TYPE dbo.AccountTableType AS TABLE
   (AccountId int, Amount decimal(18, 2))
   ```
2. Create a `Stored Procedure` with the this `User Defined Table Type`

   ```
   CREATE PROCEDURE usp_UpdateAccount
   (@tvpAccount dbo.AccountTableType READONLY)
   ```
3. Implement the `UPDATE` query with `JOIN` in the `Stored Procedure`

   ```
   UPDATE Account
   SET Account.Amount = ATT.Amount  
   FROM dbo.Account 
   INNER JOIN @tvpAccount AS ATT  
   ON dbo.Account.AccountId = ATT.AccountId;
   ```
4. Create `DataTable` and pass the required values in the Custom Type

   ```
   // Sample code
   DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
   dataTable.Columns.Add("AccountId"); //create column with correct data type
   dataTable.Columns.Add("Amount"); //create column with correct data type
   // Add rows to the table
   ...

   // Assuming the connection and command is available.
   SqlParameter tvpParam = sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tvpAccount", dataTable);  
   tvpParam.SqlDbType    = SqlDbType.Structured;  
   tvpParam.TypeName     = "dbo.AccountTableType";  

   sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
   ```

These steps explained in this Microsoft [Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parametershttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters).